# TypeScript definition to merge objects, but prevent the merging of different types in the object properties

Tags: typescript, types

I want to write a function that extends a object with another object. For example: We will call one object `src` and the other `ext`. The function has to return (a copy) of the `src` object but deeply (recursively) extends the object with the `ext` object. If the data type of one (sub-) property of the `ext` doesn't matches the type of the `src` (sub-) property the function has to ignore the `ext` value. New properties from `ext` (not existing in `src`) will be added to the result object.

For better understanding here an complete example:

```
/** A helper definition to build indexable objects */
interface indexObject<T> {
    [key: string]: T
}

type SafelyMergedObject<Src extends indexObject<any>, Ext extends indexObject<any>> = {
    // The searched type definition
}

const src= {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    c: false,
    d: {
        a: "Alice",
        b: "Bob",
    }
}
const ext = {
    a: ["a"],
    b: 1,
    c: true,
    d: {
        a: "Ann",
        c: "Clair",
    },
    e: "New value",
}
const result: SafelyMergedObject<typeof src, typeof ext> = {
    a: "a", /** Only string should be allowed here because
                it's the property type of the source (Src) type */
    b: "b", /** Same as above (`a` property) */
    c: true,/** Since `c` has the same data type the function
                should return the property value of the `ext`
                object */
    d: {    /** Same data type in both objects */
        a: "Ann",   /** new value from `ext` */
        b: "Bob",   /** copied value from `src` */
        c: "Clair", /** new property from `ext` */
    },
    e: "New Value", /** new property from `ext` */
}
```

*[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=42&pc=2#code/PQKhAIEFwCwUwDYAc4CdwBM4DMCWA7XAF1wHt9wjTwAjAV1wQ3AKwA8BDGhOcUmgFZwAxkQDO4EMACwAKAJE02DsN6s4bAPKCRRADwAVAHzgA3nPCXwAbQDWcAJ4AucGKKoCAcwC6Lg3IBfOTkiBxRwAGUObEQHAFk0TzgMbSFRPQjUYXANRXwMCXUtHXSOfAcjABpwAFE2Ihz6uHzC-I1U3T0yipMAXjMLK2BgcAN4VzgOLPhmUPCsPEISckDg2WFyN1cs-vNZK3AOFwAiDmPKwcsaE5pzy-BhF2UEMTgL-asMFz2Dg6PwY6QBC4VR3D6-WgnABC-DBByCsgRG3wW1y4F293+1lOx287wO13AAEZ8VZHpRUHQ3vcvgNwb9-oD8Pg4RCHicAMIIDi4VCsywBUmWOAnABycAA7uAAG4cBBUsFIzYNVBwMR0BBEFxRGIIeKJZIddJzOCkbDbYTVE1mxpEPp0v4nM7VUAQTT4PWudxeVwwUga5g0XhyhCkCXJWBoXhB4QcOive5s37EADkEiI4yQqFIKFQoUoYV4NozvDE-qyvAAFJlhABKAvhKT3QnHW4usCRDgAW2DEi4pGlVYABhwh+Aszm0KF6036eT3FTKq7IgRVOAh8IxzAOOnxmJu7wMBwiBwG7wS+BsHR8KIyPhE0mrGI-QHwKqiHRUBQLxPc-nZfKRbmheQ65EOD6PnwJQNLOBy0qYBzLlEPaYMep4miwFA0KQGZQWk4iSDI9KOgCkDMucQwdvgkoynKVKXtmXbrmBhEQZCAIwm2lEQBsSC4BGAH0dgjHrmIWRjrBbLkscXI8ny7YQNRUq-lODgMaQTGgfUElEfCQo5GKNEAGp0XAFHLkp47Zn+anCRpzHaaxiJAA)*

I know how to write the function. That is easy but I don't know how to write this type definition. Is that even possible?

The default TypeScript type inference behavior doesn't fit my problem because the Types are recursive and more complex than the simple `object` type. I will use the function for example to load user specific configurations into my app. The user configuration could be corrupted. So I have to merge the default configuration with the user specific configuration.

Comment: It would be good to see your function( since you know how to write it) And usually the return type is correctly infered by the compiler, so that's often not the tricky part.
It's not clear from your example what you expect the output to be since bot `src` and `ext` share the same prop name of `a`

Comment: @DamianGreen Thank you for your reply. I hope the last edit helps you to understand my problem. The mentioned function depends on a lot of other codes. I would have to shorten the code very much before posting. But maybe this edit already helps. Let me know if not.

Comment: is `SafelyMergedObject` meant to be a function? Here's its an object

Comment: @DamianGreen The SafelyMergedObject type should be the generic type that describes the merged object.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "same data type"?  Do you mean that `typeof x` and `typeof y` returns the same string at runtime?  Or do you have some other definition?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAyghgMwgGxAWQgJwOYQCYDyARgFYQDGwAPACoA0UAqgHxQC8UAFAFBR9QEAtgEtqjBgGsIIAPYIoNVgDIoAbygBtANJRhAOyhTZ8mgF0AXL37WdEAB7AIevAGdD0uUygB+LlesBmozapgw0IaZQ9o7ObhoypBTADAlklJHe-oH88EioGDj4xGnU4VqhTCHMWdlQ5gohNfwAlHUN5VAAvtyt0U6uunpImAI+apo6+u7GAhYCIV1tehAAblgA3NxAA)? It seems that you always use the source property type if it exists, but it's hard to tell without more use cases.  Can you try out the linked type and see if it works or breaks and then update your question? If it works I'll write it up.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, for my imprecise question. Your answer is exactly the right answer I was searching for. If you send it, I will mark your answer as the solution. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will interpret what you're asking for as the following: for object types `T` and `U`, the object type `SafelyMergedObject<T, U>` should have the same keys as `T & U`, but with some differences to the property types.  If a key `K` exists in just `T` or `U` but not both, then use the property as-is (so this is the same as `T & U`).  If the key `K` exists in both `T` and `U` and at least one of the two property types is not an object, then use the property type from `T` and ignore the property from `U`.  If the key `K` exists in both `T` and `U` and *is* an object type in both `T` and `U`, then recurse down into that property via `SafelyMergedObject<T[K], U[K]>`.

This gets translated into something like:

```
type SafelyMergedObject<T, U> = (
    Omit<U, keyof T> & { [K in keyof T]:
        K extends keyof U ? (
            [U[K], T[K]] extends [object, object] ?
            SafelyMergedObject<T[K], U[K]>
            : T[K]
        ) : T[K] }
) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

Here we are first outputting `Omit<U, keyof T>`, which is the properties from U that do not exist in `T`.  Then we are going through the keys of `T`, and outputting `T[K]` if the property is not in `U`, or if it is in `U` but at least one of `T[K]` or `U[K]` is not an object.

The only "trick" here is `extends infer O ? {[K in keyof O]: O[K]} : never`.  All this does is "prettify" or "expand" the object type by iterating over all the keys and merging the result into a single object type.

Let's see it in action with your `src` and `ext` values:

```
type Result = SafelyMergedObject<typeof src, typeof ext>;
```

If you hover over that with IntelliSense you'll see:

```
type Result = {
    e: string;
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
    d: {
        c: string;
        a: string;
        b: string;
    };
}
```

which is, I think, what you wanted.  Note that if I didn't include the `extends infer O...` line, the `Result` type would be evaluated as:

```
type Result = Pick<{
    a: string[];
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
    d: {
        a: string;
        c: string;
    };
    e: string;
}, "e"> & {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
    d: SafelyMergedObject<{
        a: string;
        b: string;
    }, {
        a: string;
        c: string;
    }>;
}
```

which is significantly harder to understand, although it amounts to the same type.

---

Note that there are probably all sorts of edge cases that will crop up if you use the above `SafelyMergedObject<T, U>` in different situations.  You'll need to decide what you want the output to look like in those situations and possibly tweak the definition to get those to happen.  So be careful.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAygQwGZQDZgLJQE4HMoAmA8gEYBWUAxiADwAqANDAKoB8MAvDABTAz8wiAWwCWtZkwDWUMAHskMOuwBkMAN4wA2gGkYIgHYxpchXQC6ALj4CbuqAA8QUfQQDORmfJYwA-D2s2gVrMOmZMdKFmMA5OLu6asuRUIEyJFNRRPgFBAogo6Fh4hKTptBHaYSyhrNk5MBaKobUCAJT1jRUwAL7AbQD0fTHObnr6KNiCvupaugYeJoKWgqHd7fpQAG44ANzAe5Sy+q4gMK7YlJzq2QgNAEQItwzZJHckj9mUDUgIqK5QTzYCA01M1+DcYLcAIKoESUKDvOovCEAIUSCIEPR6ByOJxilxBNnBmnutzCzwaAEYAQJPjAQNgAK7-bJAq51cFQ-T6dFBWm3ADCqAQImwPO61P4UDuADkoAB3GAbH5M949UCQWAAJSgrgZqBOXDyaEwOHwxCS1Bo4GgXjOlCY1qgXhirF2fQAVHSNTBtbr9fjslLTvSDLhdoSGsdsKHwwIkVGYx8GiRZLJUFAEPpY-xWQScrSE-ow6CYODC8XEZGQ0Xs91dl0YO6+ntgB6vdAfTq9QaYAAFWGSGh5sFV6NFzRmWtI-QMoQkHZJmAptMZrMs4ElsvViv50eJmxdWtB8v1pi3eEqNkCLdjnf8ePb2u05fpzO11lGgqm4oW2jDwI3vuOQPretZdEw-4RsGoElgWj7ZF0rrAA2TZ7EAA)